# Why I can't get django_comments in the admin

Tags: django-admin, django-comments

The version of django is 1.10 and Python version is 2.7.6 .After I have migrate and create table,it showed that I have migrated the django_comments.When I get into my admin,I can't find the django_comments app. 
By the way,I have installed django_comments.And I can use it normally on the front side.

Comment: Have you registered the model in your `admin.py`?

Comment: @VLeong django_comments is a thing which replace django-contrib-comments.It doesn't need to be registered in admin

Comment: Is this what you used? https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments

Comment: @VLeong Yes,I use it and I found it isn't shown in the admin

Comment: I really think you have to register it in the admin. Please try doing that. Refer to my answer below.

Comment: @VLeong ok,I try it and it can work normally,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in apps like `django.contrib.sites` automatically registers its model in the admin. I believe that since `django_comments` is now a separated app from the django core, you'll have to register the model in the admin to see it.

If you've successfully migrated `django_comments` and used it, then I think you're just missing the admin registration.

I started a brand new Django project to test this out, and I got to see the `Comments` in my admin.

Using Python 2.7.12...

- `pip install django`
- `pip install django-contrib-comments`
- `django-admin startproject main`
- Put my project `main` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`
- Followed steps 1 to 5 in the quickstart guide for `django-contrib-comments` (https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)
- `python manage.py migrate`
- Included the following code in `main/admin.py` (create the file if it's not there):

  ```
  from django_comments.models import Comment

  admin.site.register(Comment)
  ```
- `python manage.py runserver`
- Ran browser and logged into admin
- Comment is there

[image]